# What is command to redirect the lines from one file to another file

Tags: linux, io-redirection, pattern-matching

I want to redirect the lines which contain "hello" from file1 to file 2 in Unix. What is the command used here?

Comment: Are you wanting to copy the entire contents of file1 to file2? You could do $cat file1 > file2 (overwrite file2 contents) or $cat file1 >> file2 to append

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. I have at least 3 interpretations of what you are trying to do. Please edit question to make it clear.

Comment: @EDubman no ,...the lines which contain hello

Comment: What about lines that contain `shello` or `hello2`?

Answer (score 2):

You will need the command `grep`. (`man grep`).

And file redirection `>`. (`man bash`)

From grep manual

```
.
.
.
SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
.
.
.
       -F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
.
.
.
```

I recommend reading this manual, more fully.

Comment: Where to mention the hello in syntax?

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook use of grep, so much so that it's called "grepping" as a verb much more often than it's called redirecting.

```
fgrep hello file.txt > file2.txt
```

`fgrep` is a variant of `grep` that only looks for `f`ixed strings (as opposed to matching *regular expressions*, the `re` in `grep`). The standard equivalent is `grep -F`, though you'll find ancient `grep` implementations like Solaris' `/bin/grep` that don't support the `-F` option yet.

Comment: fgrep/ grep what's the difference

Comment: See man grep. frep is exactly equivalent to grep -F, which is however the preferred form. The -F is useful for Fixed Strings as patterns: it optimises by not invoking pattern matching, and it also stops special pattern characters being misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer

```
sed -i -e '/hello/{ w file2.txt' -e 'd;}'  file1.txt
```

(*moves* the matching lines into `file2.txt`)

Or

```
grep "hello"  file1.txt  > file2.txt
```

(*copies* the matching lines into `file2.txt`)

Comment: Could you possibly describe the `sed` command? It is nontrivial and I'm having issues following what's actually happening. Aren't you, for example, modifying `file1.txt` there? Additionally, that `-e` looks misplaced.